# Raspberry PI 2 - How to get file-access for c-program to write on disc

Tags: c, eclipse, sqlite, file

i am using Raspbian on a RPI2 and i tried to create/change a SQLite database from a C-Program.

here a little bit code:

```
static sqlite3 *db;
static char *zErrMsg    = 0;
//....
sqlite3_open(PATH_DATABASE, &db);
char *sql_statement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTable (datetime BIGINT, myVal BIGINT)";
sqlite3_exec(db,sql_statement, NULL, NULL, &zErrMsg);

sqlite3_close(db);
```

As IDE i use Eclipse CDT.

In Eclipse Debug-Mode and with executing the program by double click (in "sudo startx" mode), raspbian creates me a database file.

If i start my program via terminal (sudo /home/pi/test/myProgram)
no database-file could be created.

Folder "test" and executable "myProgram" have both chmod 755 access.
I searched a lot, found nothing that helps me.

Comment: Why do you execute your program as root (with sudo)?

Comment: sqlite3_open returns an error code. Check what it is.

Comment: Can you try to run the binary under `strace` and show us the output?

Comment: I got a solution for my specific problem. If i use "cd /home/pi/test" and after "./myProgram" it worked (without sudo). If i try to start by "sudo /home/pi/test/myProgram" it still not work. Now i want to know why. I think there are some permission/access reasons. 
Perhaps one of you is smarter than me and can explain it.

Comment: Perhaps the program is running in a different directory if you use "sudo". Or perhaps something prevents sqlite3 opening files when run as root. You can probably learn more from an `strace` as suggested above.

Answer (score 2):

Each one of the `sqlite3` functions returns an error code. After *every* call, check that the error code is `SQLITE_OK`. If it isn't, then the function failed, and you need to handle the error.

You can call `sqlite3_errstr` to convert the error code to a string.

For more information about error handling in sqlite3, see https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html .

Comment: ErrStr:" unable to open database" ... Well ... I got a solution that works for me. If i use "cd /home/pi/test" and after "./myProgram" it worked (without sudo). If i try to start by "sudo /home/pi/test/myProgram" it still not work. Now i want to know why. I think there are some permission/access reasons. 
Perhaps one of you is smarter than me and can explain it.